# program to tell if object is in focal length of camera #emgucv

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I am working on a project where i need robot to move towards the object until object reaches inside focal length of camera. I need to know if there is any built in function in emgucv library to help me with this or if some one can help me with code to achieve it.
I am using emgucv library and c# for image processing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use some variation of any of the following algorithms:

- Contrast measurement
- Edge detection (Sobel, Canny)
- Variance or Standard Deviation
- Thresholded Gradient Magnitude
- High Pass Filtering

OpenCV (which emgucv is a wrapper for) has all of the functions you'll need to implement any of the above algorithms. If you would like specific help with any of the above algorithms, try implementing one and post the code if you get stuck. People generally are more apt to assist with programming when you first display some level of research and effort, with all due respect.

One issue you'll encounter is that depending on the object, if the object has variable depths (holes, dips, bumps, etc), your focal length will only allow a surface at that point to be in focus. Graphing the results of the above algorithms versus the encoder position of the robot will give you the surface position with the greatest focus number. If you need to focus on just a bump, you'll need to detect which XY position on the part that you want to focus on.